# Can “my mother” be not a member of my family in a specific context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I played a game. I should make people and raise them in this role-playing game. I made a family. Of course, I also made a mother of a son I made. So, this mother belongs to me.

Can I call her “my mother” in this specific context as a creator of this mother?

> the creator, supervisor, user, etc. of the "possessed" (Prince's
> album, the Irish jockey's horse).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in this very specific context, and with the intention of identifying the character as the one you created.

> Susie, your mother is a level 4 elf with +2 insight, and my mother is a barbarian rogue wielding a spatula of destiny.

You can say "my mother NPC" or similar to make it clear you mean an NPC in the game, not your real mother.

If you don't need to clarify you can just say "The mother"

> For this game I've created a family.  The mother's stats are ...

Or just give her a name:

> I've created a family. The mother is named Jolene and she...

Clearly this is very specific and very rare context.

Comment: It’s like “my favourite food” can mean “my food preferred by people”?

Comment: Only in a super rare context. I'm struggling to think of an example where "my favourite food" would mean that.

Comment: I suspect you are thinking backwards.  You're trying to see if unnatural meanings are possible.  You're not thinking of language for communication.  If you were thinking of communication, you would use "my mother" to mean the person who gave birth to you, and "my favourite food" to mean the food the you like most, and not try to design contexts that might make the expressions mean something else.

Comment: Sorry, I thought language is like logic. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119935/difference-between-not-every-and-every-is-not

Comment: See Daniel G. Wilson‘s logical approach. I thought it was valid.

Comment: No!!  Language can be used to express logical ideas.  But language is *not* like logic.  Logic is about the truth or falsehood of prepositions.  Language is about communication (and much more)  Daniel agrees.  The expression is a proposition, and so a logical approach is possible, but Daniel says, "you are able to discern the intended meaning of Karan's comment, even with its incorrect phrasing", which means that there must be more than logic.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that even in this circumstance your "mother" is still a member of your "family", it is just that the mother and family being discussed are your game characters, not your flesh-and-blood biological family. Even when talking about actual people there might be times where a mother is specifically not part of the family being discussed, say someone talking about their spouse and children. Very often with natural language discerning actual meaning comes down to context. Sometimes (such as in legal documents) it is important to do as much as possible to remove those ambiguities, more frequently (casual conversation) it is not.

If your conversation with someone is already about this game it is very likely that simply saying "mother bakes some cookies" will be understood to be talking about the game character rather than your flesh-and-blood mother, particularly if said flesh-and-blood mother isn't physically close enough to involve herself in whatever is going on.